# Usernames starting with a multi character character are not rendered as expected?

Tags: bug, design, display-names, special-characters

<sub>For previous versions of this question, please see its [history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/370185/revisions)</sub>

---

Usernames which <s>include</s> *start with* (eg) an [Arabic Damma](https://www.unicodepedia.com/unicode/arabic/64f/arabic-damma/) are not rendered correctly:

[image: "Ė" in username on homepage has shading behind it]

<sup>Screenshot taken from [Stack Overflow's homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302964/populate-and-exepopulate-didnt-work-in-mongoose-js-and-node-js-project).</sup>

---

- Thanks to [@Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370185/username-with-%c4%96-does-not-render-as-expected#comment1235418_370185) for pointing out the correct char.
- As [@41686d6564](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/348196/41686d6564) points out; this is probably an accident

---

Copy/pasted username:

> ُEslam Talabe Garibe Qoutbe

Which consists out of:

- `U+064F`: Arabic Damma <sup>[[unicodepedia](https://www.unicodepedia.com/unicode/arabic/64f/arabic-damma/)]</sup>
- `U+0045`: Latin Capital Letter <sup>[[unicodepedia](https://www.unicodepedia.com/unicode/basic-latin/45/latin-capital-letter-e/)]</sup>

---

Device information:

- macOS v10.15.7 (Catalina)  (19H2)
- Google Chrome Version 93.0.4577.82 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: Could you link to an example so that the bug can be reproduced?

Comment: It's on the StackOverflow homepage, did not yet find any other page with the same issue.

Comment: That's unfortunate, because the Stack Overflow homepage both 1) changes extremely frequently and 2) is quite user-specific.

Comment: ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302964/populate-and-exepopulate-didnt-work-in-mongoose-js-and-node-js-project i get an entirely different character? I can find [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5609534/%c3%8bsl%c3%a2m-m%c3%a2hm%c3%b4ud) with the character you mention

Comment: @KevinB That looks like an E with a single open circle on the profile page but an accent on the question page. :/ Though that could be due to text size.

Comment: if you look at the two user profiles, it's definitely two different characters, weirdness abound

Comment: Yea Im questioning the char. Looked like an `Ë` in the inspector, but on the profile page, it seems like an `E` with a single dot on the left side.  Copy/pasting the char in the question fails as well

Comment: In this case, the E is made up of two characters  ُ    `E`

Comment: Isn't it an [Arabic Damma](https://www.unicodepedia.com/unicode/arabic/64f/arabic-damma/) on an E. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI4cj.png - Which renders correctly using FF Android.

Comment: So maybe the question should be titled: **Usernames *starting* with an multi character character are not rendered as expected**?

Comment: FWIW i recreated the "interesting question" highlight for one of this user's questions on the search page, and couldn't recreate the issue, chrome, windows. I get the little swirl loop (which may or may not be correct, but i don't get the weird background bit)

Comment: It's not a single dotted E, see my prior comment.

Comment: @rob It _is_ an Arabic Damma. OP says that it only renders incorrectly on the homepage though.

Comment: @Rob Yes, you're spot on, it's `U+064F : Arabic Damma` + `U+0045 : Latin Capital Letter E`. Anyone else can verify this by copying and pasting the name/ character into a character identification tool [like this one](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html?string=ُE).

Comment: _"but it seems to be an Ė"_ No, it's not. It's two chars: a `ُ` followed by an `E`. A little more insight on how this probably happened (by accident): on an Arabic/English keyboard, the same key (in combination with Shift) is used to write both a capital E and a "Damma" (depending on the active typing language). The user likely tried to type "E" while "Arabic" was selected, realized their mistake, switched to English, but didn't notice (or forgot to delete) the Damma, then started typing their name in English.

Comment: In reference to [41686d6564's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370185/username-with-%c4%96-does-not-render-as-expected#comment1235422_370185): The post has drifted down to [page 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page=11), and off the [homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/), but it still [appears as a Damma E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv0fX.png). **Elsewhere** [on the Internet there are 13 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=Talabe%20Garibe%20Qoutbe), where it appears as Damma E or E; and not as described by the OP. --- Browser / OS (font) specific.

Comment: I would state that on my Firefox the rendering seem not the same as other, it's definetly like @Rob, but arabic sign seem not placed at the same place. [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhuUk.jpg)

Comment: It is possible that it is an [Egyptian name](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D9%8FEslam+Egypt&filter=0).

Comment: Not reproducible on Chrome, it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?tab=newest&page=21&pagesize=50)

Comment: [A more stable view](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmongoose%5D+%5Bjavascript%5D+%5Bnode.js%5D+user%3A13026210). Does this exhibit the problem?

Comment: @Rob It is indeed an Egyptian/Arab name (just "Eslam" without the damma). You'd never use a damma for the first letter of that name. Actually, you don't really need diacritics at all for that letter in that word because it's implied. But if for some reason you wanted to explicitly use diacritics there, the correct one would be [Kasra](https://www.unicodepedia.com/unicode/arabic/650/arabic-kasra/), not Damma. The only reason you'd see it written that way is if it's by accident (most likely) or someone just uses diacritics incorrectly to "decorate" text (Source: I'm a native Arabic speaker :D).

Comment: @41686d6564 Do you agree that the diacritics are usually used to: teach pronunciation, when the pronunciation changed over a long period of time and to clarify, or for religious texts; and not for common usage? --- Most likely a [KBD error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370185/username-with-%c4%96-does-not-render-as-expected?noredirect=1#comment1235424_370185) but perhaps it's a common occurrence, as they're not the only one with a Dammah on their letter E. --- In light of the usage, would you say that yagmoth555's positioning (see their comment) is wrong, it's 3/4 high, not "top".

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q, there's a problem with that "[stable view](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmongoose%5D+%5Bjavascript%5D+%5Bnode.js%5D+user%3A13026210)" in that it doesn't render the same as the [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13026210/%d9%8feslam-talabe-garibe-qoutbe). See [differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f32Dz.png).

Comment: @Rob _"teach pronunciation"_  and _"for religious texts"_ Correct. _"when the pronunciation changed over a long period of time"_ Not sure what you mean. _"not for common usage"_ It can still be used for common usage to disambiguate the pronunciation. Some words are written exactly the same but have different meanings and pronunciations. The only way to differentiate between them is with diacritics or by inferring it from context. Sometimes, the context is not enough for the average native speaker. [1/2]

Comment: @Rob _"yagmoth555's positioning"_ That's likely just due to different fonts. It's the same characters in both yagmoth555's screenshot and yours (i.e., a damma followed by an E). Note that Arabic diacritics are not supposed to be used with Latin script; so, it's understandable that it could look weird (e.g., partially hidden behind the letter like in your screenshot). [2/2]